# Date Format in Sql to SSRS mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.nnn AM/PM

Tags: sql-server, reportingservices-2005

I need to get the exact date time to SSRS, I noticed when I use a date field the milliseconds get cut off in SSRS so I was thinking about formatting a string.  I could not find a convert option that match the output I needed

`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.nnn AM/PM`

So I came up with this long formula

```
-- Test Data
DECLARE @DATETIMESTAMP DATETIME 
SET @DATETIMESTAMP = GETDATE()
------------
SELECT DISTINCT 
    RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(@DateTimeStamp)), 2) + '/' +
    RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DAY(@DateTimeStamp)), 2) + '/' +
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(@DateTimeStamp)) + ' ' +
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @DateTimeStamp) > 12 THEN RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(HOUR, @DateTimeStamp)-12), 2)
        WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @DateTimeStamp) = 0 THEN '12'
        ELSE RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(HOUR, @DateTimeStamp)), 2)
    END + ':' +
    RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(MINUTE, @DateTimeStamp)), 2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(SECOND, @DateTimeStamp)), 2) + '.' +
    RIGHT('000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(MILLISECOND, @DateTimeStamp)), 3) + ' ' +
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @DateTimeStamp) > 11 THEN 'PM'
        ELSE 'AM'
    END 
    ,@DateTimeStamp
```

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Here is a picture of the report: This is using my code
[image]

If I just pass back @DATETIMESTAMP I would get just
`11/20/2013 02:23:19 PM`

Then when running the query no records would match because `11/20/2013 02:23:19.000 PM` to `11/20/2013 02:23:19.083 PM`

Comment: Why are you formatting date/time in SQL instead of the output layer, like SSRS or an application?

Comment: Agreed.  SSRS supports formatting in the front-end.  No need to convert to a string in the data source.

Comment: What is the DISTINCT for?

Comment: in the original data set two items can occur at the same time, very unlikely but possible.  This is also for a parameter so I don't think formatting is really available.

Comment: A parameter for what? Why would you need a parameter to be in any specific format? You're much better off keeping it in its native data type when possible.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a timestamp to identify a row. Since timestamps aren't unique (two things *can* happen at the same time), what do you plan to do when your report matches on two rows?

Comment: Return both rows, even though the likely hood of this happening are 1000 to 1 against since we are now filtering by owner also.  Again I agree with you, the first parameter to the left I cut out of the pic was a Batch Number per se, but people complained they could not remember the batch number.  Now I can hide the millisecond in the label and the exact value in value, but again that is what the customer 'wanted'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geez, that's a lot of busy work that should probably be handled by SSRS. You can do it in T-SQL, but there is a lot of overhead in formatting strings there instead of just returning the native data. Here is one way that yields `11/25/2013 3:03:12.567PM`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(11), GETDATE(), 101)
  + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(26), GETDATE(), 9), 14));
```

If you really need the space between the milliseconds and AM/PM, then you can get there with a little more work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(11), GETDATE(), 101)
  + LTRIM(STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(26), GETDATE(), 9), 14),13,0,' '));
```

And if you really need the leading 0, it gets even more fun:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(11), GETDATE(), 101)
  + RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(26), GETDATE(), 9), 14),13,0,' ')),15);
```

In SQL Server 2012, you'll be able to say:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt');
```

But again, these methods of formatting strings in SQL Server force a lot of extra CPU overhead on the database that is much better handled by the presentation layer - which has to treat every row independently anyway. SQL Server only has to treat a set as a bunch of independent rows when you force it to, by applying formatting and other things, and this can slow the query down significantly.

Never mind that `mm/dd/yyyy` is very irresponsible output. Are you sure your entire audience will always understand that 06/09/2013 is June 9th and not September 6th?

Comment: I brought up the point you raise, but that is what they want.

Comment: @Aaron if it is some heavy processing is it not better to do it on sql server rather than doing it on SSRS ?

Comment: @MuhammedAli Why do you think the database is better / more efficient at formatting strings than SSRS?

Comment: This is close, just need to changed the last : to a .

Answer (score 3):

Use the following format in SSRS:

```
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt
```

This returns:

```
11/25/2013 11:41:51.067 AM
```

Keep the data type as DATETIME in your source query.  You don't need to convert the output to string.  Use the application layer, in this case SSRS, to control the format.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME;
SET  @Date  = GETDATE()

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Date, 101) + ' '
            +  RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), @Date, 109), 14)
```

**Result**

```
11/25/2013 7:44:23:330PM
```

Comment: who down voted my answer and why? would like to know your reason please ??

Comment: I did. Here's why: (1) This breaks if the hour is 10, 11 or 12 (whether AM or PM) - it truncates the first digit. You used the current time as a use case but didn't test what I hesitate to call an "edge" case - e.g. 4 hours from now. (2) You declare `@Date` but then don't bother using it. If the OP actually takes your code and makes `@Date` a parameter, they might be confused why the code that should be using the parameter doesn't actually work unless they pass `GETDATE()` to the parameter (in which case it's just a coincidence).

Comment: I did too. But I just jump on the band wagon.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I have fixed the issue Aaron raised and yet you down voted anyway have you ever heard the story of that monkey who some how got hold of a match box, he endup putting the whole jungle on fire. if you know what i mean pal. take it easy mate

Comment: So now you need to think about - given the number of corrections you had to make that other people noticed - what makes your answer different from - never mind superior to - ones that existed long before yours? (Also, since they are using SSRS 2005, I assume the underlying database is also SQL Server 2005. In which case your `DECLARE @Date DATETIME = GETDATE()` won't work.)

Comment: (In other words, what is your answer bringing to the table that makes it not a duplicate? Is it more efficient than earlier answers that produce the same result? Is it more reliable? If not, then it's just a duplicate.)

Comment: No it isnt duplicate of any answer, none of the answers used the approach I have used. Even your answer at that time had more code than my answer, Yes I did declare the variable and forgot to use it in the solution and I did over look the fact question had sql-server 2005 tag in it. so I did use the inline declaration but it was for only demo purpose Im sure user is not going to use a variable it will be used on some column.

Comment: "your answer at that time had more code than my answer" - uh, what? Could you please elaborate, because I have no idea what you're talking about. My answer existed 5 minutes before yours did and I can assure you that [the first version of my answer contained the first two code samples as they exist now - 100% identical](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20201776/1). I added clarifications to assist in getting *exactly* the output the OP requested, if absolutely necessary - which your answer *still* does not do, even after I corrected the most basic mistakes. Please stop making nonsense up.

Comment: Your allegation that I tidied up my answer once I saw your tidier code is absolutely ridiculous. Even if I had done that, since your answer appeared 5 minutes after mine did, any edit I made based on your post (which was totally wrong at that time, remember?) would have happened outside the grace period and therefore would show up in my post's revisions. There's this thing called etiquette, you should look it up. I bump into you on nonsense like this often enough that I wonder what you think it makes you look like, lying to try to appear "right" in some way...

Comment: *"had more code than my answer"*. @MuhammedAli, less code does not always mean better / more correct / more efficient code.

Comment: Aaron I have a lot of respect for you because of your knowledge, I am sorry it came out a bit wrong I am not comparing my answers with yours, I am on this site to share what I know with the people who are relatively new with sql and to learn from people like you. I was in edit window was already open and I didnt realise that you have already answered the question, Normally I dont answer to the question where you have already cuz I prefer to read your answers and learn something from them, I do apologize pal.

Comment: @ypercube yes it was a silly statement, and thankyou for your input